# Is there a way to access superclass variables in subclass with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I was learning JavaScript oops with some sample example when I came across to access superclass methods in subclass which is possible with super keyword
but when I try to access or return a variable of super class it returns undefined or the sub class variable I tried in various way to get variable

I have also gone [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14312921/javascript-polymorphism-variable-inheritance) Stack Overflow post.

```js
class dad {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    printname() {
        console.log(this.name);
        var a = 2;
        return a;
    }
    sendVal() {
        console.log(this.name);
        var a = 2;
        return this.name;
    }
}

class son extends dad {
    constructor(name) {
        super(name);
    }
    printname() {
        console.log(super.printname());

    }
    printvariable() {
        console.log(super.name);

    }
    getvalue() {
        console.log(super.sendVal())
    }
}

var o1 = new dad('jackson');
var o2 = new son('jack')

o1.printname()
o2.printname()
o2.printvariable()
o2.getvalue()
```

Comment: You can certainly call methods that come from a superclass, but what do you expect `console.log(super.name)` to do that's different from `console.log(this.name)`?

Answer (score 13):

When you use `super.fieldName` to access a field of a parent class, you are actually querying the field name on the `prototype` of the parent class.

So you might believe calling `super(name);` from the `Son` constructor sets the `name` in the prototype of the parent class, but it is **not** so, it actually sets the `name` property **inherited** by the `Son` class which you can access by using `this.name`.

So I modified your example code and shown how to actually get a value by calling `super.fieldName`. In the example I added a property `age` in the prototype of the `Dad` class and set its value to `50`, now in the `Son` class `printvariable()` will correctly call the `super.age` by referring the prototype of the `Dad` class.

You can actually see it in action if you use babel to transpile it to ES2015, after all classes in JavaScript are actually syntactic sugar.

```js
class Dad {
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
        Dad.prototype.age = 50; //adding property to prototype
    }
    printname() {
        console.log(this.name);
        var a = 2;
        return a;
    }
    sendVal() {
        console.log(this.name);
        var a = 2;
        return this.name;
    }
}

class Son extends Dad {
    constructor(name) {
        super(name);
    }
    printname() {
        console.log(super.printname());

    }
    printvariable() {
        console.log(`super.name will be undefined, as not present in prototype of the Dad class: ${super.name}`);
        console.log(`super.age will have a value of 50, present in the prototype of the Dad class: ${super.age}`);
        console.log(`this.name will be jack, as it is set from the constructor of the Son class: ${this.name}`);

    }
    getvalue() {
        console.log(super.sendVal());
    }
}

var o1 = new Dad('jackson');
var o2 = new Son('jack')

o1.printname();
o2.printname();
o2.printvariable();
o2.getvalue();
```